# "I've got a place at college, so do I"

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

Is the sentence "I've got a place at college, so do I" grammatically correct? if yes, what does "so do I" add in the meaning?

Comment: Where did this come from? Barring context, I would assume it was a typo or transcribed erroneously, with the normal (colloquial) version being *I've got a place at college, so **I do**.*

Comment: The "...so I do, so it is, so I am, so you are", etc, finish to a statement is mainly Irish, I think, particularly Northern. British TV viewers may recall Jim McDonald from _Coronation Street_, so they may.

Comment: @JasonBassford,I was thinking why not "...so have I."  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically correct, but there's something wrong. "So do I" would be expected from a different person responding to the first part of the sentence, or "so I do" might be said by someone with a particular speech pattern (I associate it with the UK more than the US, for some reason). One person would not say the entire sentence, it wouldn't make sense.